# What is the advantage of [inittest] in Kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel

```
 /* Each module must use one module_init(). */
#define module_init(initfn)                 \
    static inline initcall_t __inittest(void)       \
    { return initfn; }                  \
    int init_module(void) __attribute__((alias(#initfn)));
```

Answer (score 4):

The sole purpose of the generated `__inittest()` function it to check during compile time, that the function passed to `module_init()` macro is compatible with the `initcall_t` type.

All module initialization functions must conform to the type, since (as can be seen from the `init_module()` definition) they are not called directly, but rather are called via special aliased name `init_module()`.